# matplotlib hist: how to plot a stacked hist with y_axis equal to 100%

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
x=np.random.randn(1000)
y=np.random.randn(1000)
plt.hist([x,y],bins=np.arange(-5,5,1),stacked=True,normed=True)
```

I am sorry China is blocked form image website of stackoverflow. I don't know whether you can see my picture. Since the codes are all there, you can run it.

[image]

I want y_axis equal to 100%, and the graph should show the percentage of x and y in every interval. That is:
[image]

I draw it manually...

Comment: If it's too difficult for matplotlib, then ggplot/seaborn or any other python package is ok as long as it can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is a simple option of matplotlib's hist-plot.

However, you could calculate the histograms of both variables x and y with numpy's histogram function, then calculate the fractions of the sum of both and plot the data with a standard barplot:

```
plt.figure()
x=np.random.randn(1000)
y=np.random.randn(1000)
hx = np.histogram(x, bins=np.arange(-5, 5, 1))
hy = np.histogram(y, bins=np.arange(-5, 5, 1))
s = hx[0] + hy[0]
plt.bar(hx[1][:-1], hx[0]/s, label='x')
plt.bar(hy[1][:-1], hy[0]/s, bottom=hx[0]/s, label='y')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

*For having percentages instead of fractions on the y-axis you simply could multiply all the y-values by 100:*

```
plt.bar(hx[1][:-1], hx[0]/s*100, label='x')
plt.bar(hy[1][:-1], hy[0]/s*100, bottom=hx[0]/s*100, label='y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib gives us access to the rectangles it displays and we can manipulate them. The following code assumes that all bins are of the same size, so that we only need to 
scale the heights.

```py
x=np.random.randn(1000)
y=np.random.randn(1000)
h = plt.hist([x,y],bins=np.arange(-5,5,1),stacked=True,density=True)

p1, p2 = h[-1] # the rectangles for bottom and top bars

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-5, 5, 1))

# go through each pair (bottom, top) and change the positions and length.
for i, (h1, h2) in enumerate(zip(p1.patches, p2.patches)):
    h1_h = h1.get_height()
    h2_h = h2.get_height()
    if h1_h == 0 or h2_h == 0:
        continue
    h = h1_h+h2_h
    h1.set_y(0)
    h1.set_height(h1_h/h * 100)
    h2.set_y(h1_h/h * 100)
    h2.set_height(h2_h/h * 100)

    h1.set_edgecolor('white')
    h2.set_edgecolor('white')
    h1.set_linewidth(1)
    h2.set_linewidth(1)
```

[Stacked histogram after scaling to 0-100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN1OP.png)

After edits: [Stacked histogram after scaling to 0-100 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwWTN.png)

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Prasanth

Comment: That's true!! To make it more legible we can, for example, add a thicker border. Add the following to the loop:     `h1.set_edgecolor('white') h2.set_edgecolor('white')  h1.set_linewidth(1)
    h2.set_linewidth(1)`.  Hope this helps. Sorry for the formatting; typing enter in the comment simply submits the commit.

Comment: I have edited the answer to add proper ticks and show separation between bars.